# iOS Font Not Properly Displaying All Unicode Characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

Example of two characters: U+22FF, U+23BA... and many others.

Is this an encoding layer that I'm misunderstanding for iOS? Like, at some point it no longer can properly display codes beyond 22B...?

I'm capturing this in an NSString, and trying to simply update a text field. Something like

```
NSString *test = @"\u23ba";
[displayText setText:test];
```

This will display a standard type error like a box with a question mark in it, or just a box (depending on the font).

Is there a way to expand the unicode options for iOS? Because these can be displayed on my Mac. Or, is my only option some variant of the NSAttributableString route?

Comment: is 23ba is right unicode? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23ba/index.htm

Comment: make \u23BA (B n A are capital) and see what you get...

Comment: @FahimParkar Unfortunately that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U+22FF and U+23BA are valid codepoints (assigned to characters). But they are supported by a few fonts only. So you should first check which font(s) are being used, or available.

For example, U+22FF is included in Asana-Math, Cambria, Cambria Math, Code2000, DejaVu Sans (oddly, only Bold Oblique typefaces), FreeSerif, GNU Unifont, Quivira, Segoe UI Symbol, STIXMath, STX, Sun-ExtA, Symbola, XITS, XITSMath. U+23BA is included in Cambria, Cambria Math, Code2000, FreeMono, FreeSerif, GNU Unifont, Quivira, Segoe UI Symbol, Sun-ExtA, Symbola. Many of these are free fonts. Typographic quality varies a lot. Cambria fonts and Segoe UI Symbol are commercial, shipped with some Microsoft products. There are probably some other fonts that cover those characters, but not many (Everson Mono, I suppose, I don’t currently have it).

Comment: This is what I thought as well, however, not even the system font seems to be capable of displaying these types of characters. Is there one that 'is known' to contain a larger percentage of characters?

Comment: Added some specific font info

Comment: Well, you're completely right! It looks like I'm stuck with a very limited number of fonts if I want to use some of the unicode characters, or traveling down the attributable string rabbit hole.